# Join or Concatenate Two Powershell Variables

Tags: powershell, variables

Trying to concatenate two variables with an array inside them.

***First variable contains:***

```
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $svcStatus

    Response Status
    -------- ------
         200 OK
```

***Second variable contains:***

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $svcCall 

displayName     serviceTypeUrl                                                                                port servicePort
-----------     --------------                                                                                ---- -----------
AutnTestService http://demo1.ravn.co.uk/ravn-manage/api/v2/service_types/0310bf36-8fbd-4543-a79e-2b59f288d7e3 9000        9002
```

**When they are joined:**

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>$mansvcApp = -join $svcStatus, $svcCall
$mansvcApp 
@{Response=200; Status=OK}

displayName     serviceTypeUrl                                                                                port servicePort
-----------     --------------                                                                                ---- -----------
AutnTestService http://demo1.ravn.co.uk/ravn-manage/api/v2/service_types/0310bf36-8fbd-4543-a79e-2b59f288d7e3 9000        9002
```

**How can I get it to look like this:**

```
displayName     serviceTypeUrl                                          port servicePort Response status
-----------     --------------                                          ---- ----------- -------- ------
AutnTestService http://demo1.blah.co.uk/blah/api/v2/service_types/0310b 9000    9002        200     OK
```

Comment: `-join` should be used to join elements of an array into a string like this: `$MyArray -join ","`

Answer (score 2):

One way you could do it is like this:

```
$svcStatus | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name displayname -Value $svcCall.displayname
$svcStatus | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name serviceTypeUrl -Value $svcCall.serviceTypeUrl
```

If you have several columns to add and you don't want to a lot of typing then you could use a loop to do it like so:

```
$svcCall | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | % {
    $n = $_.name
    $svcStatus | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $n -Value $svcCall."$n"
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Just what I was looking for. For better understanding why did you append $svcCall.displayname at the end.

Comment: -Name displayname -Value $svcCall.displayname indicates to me that you are appending the ending entries from svcCall to svcStatus.displayname. Shouldn't  -Name be reflective of what the name of one of the tables within svcCall should be.